# Checking into an open graph api page

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to use facebook checkin app to checkin into an open graph page ID instead of having to use touch.facebook.com or an iphone?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

if your open graph page has coordinates in the meta data like this:

```
    <html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    ...
    [REQUIRED TAGS]
    <meta property="og:latitude" content="37.416343"/>
    <meta property="og:longitude" content="-122.153013"/>
    <meta property="og:street-address" content="1601 S California Ave"/>
    <meta property="og:locality" content="Palo Alto"/>
    <meta property="og:region" content="CA"/>
    <meta property="og:postal-code" content="94304"/>
    <meta property="og:country-name" content="USA"/>
    ...
  </head>
```

would it work? An  open graph page would have an ID and could this ID work for the checkin app?

Is it possible for me to create an open graph page and use it with the checkin app or does this only work for established businesses with established physical locations?

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering the same thing. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526351/facebook-places-checkin-using-open-graph-protocol-id-as-place-id) might help.