# Facebook places checkin using open graph protocol ID as place ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I used the [FB page linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/facebook.html) to verify that all the meta information I'm using is correct.  According to the [graph url](http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/facebook.html), my page id is 157797447612809, yet when I try to publish a checkin to [this page](http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/facebook.html), i receive the error:

```
(#100) Requires a valid Place Page ID
```

Surprisingly, there is no good information about publishing a checkin to an open graph page available anywhere on the internet.  I've used every possible variation of my place page ID that I could imagine, from the URL to page id's of different pages, yet I always get this same error.  Does anyone have an example on how this should be accomplished?  Thanks!

Comment: not so surprisingly - fb docs are just terrible.

Comment: well i would at the least expect to find a blog post or SO post about checking in to an open graph page considering that there must be plenty of people who have figured it out.  It's really frustrating because I can SEE that its NOT an invalid id, yet the error response says that it is.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is absolutely no documentation by Facebook on this matter, I solved this by looking at what foursquare has done and a lot of trial and error.

When defining your open graph object within facebook, you must add a property of type **GeoPoint**. I called mine location. Define in the object page meta like this:

```
  <meta property="mytestapp:location:latitude" content="37.791" />
  <meta property="mytestapp:location:longitude" content="-122.395" />
```

Now when you debug/lint this object it register as a place, just like the [foursquare HQ](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://foursquare.com/v/foursquare-hq/4ab7e57cf964a5205f7b20e3). You can check in and create map views for actions that include this object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to add at least the location related tags e.g. og:longitude & og:latitude.

See this graph output for a page that has these og tags and checkins.

> http://graph.facebook.com/149998791679075
>
> http://foursquare.com/venue/128530

BTW: I hope you get the irony of this example 8)

I'm also not sure if you can checkin to a og:type=food page.  It may have to be one of the places types e.g. landmark - see types info on the OpenGraph page.  However the example above is for og:type=company so you'd need to test the different types to see.

Comment: Very good information.  If I try to check in to id of the foursquare HQ page, then I can get past the original error (I then get an error telling me I'm too far from the place to checkin.)  But I still get the same error with the page id for my page.  I changed the url a few days ago, does facebook still have to crawl this page before i can check in to it, possibly?  The businesses that i'm trying to check in to have multiple coordinates, so hopefully lat and lng arent required.

Comment: Yeah...you need to run the URL through Facebook linkter like you first did for it to get picked up by the system I think.  Also, I've done a lot of testing since my first answer and it seems that OpenGraph based pages don't work with Checkins, Events or Places even though the docs say they do 8(  You should raise this as a bug with Facebook and I'll do the same.

Comment: I've been running my page through the linter every time i change the markup and it's still giving me the same error.  See http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fvenue%2F151523 ,and then the lint for my site http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foodtrucksmap.com%2Ffacebook.html .  But they look differently on the graph:  http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foodtrucksmap.com%2Ffacebook.html and http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fvenue%2F151523

Answer (score 0):

The Geopoint object is described here:

https://developers.dev.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/complextypes/#geopoint

Example:

```
<meta property="your-og-app:location:latitude"  content="37.416382"> 
<meta property="your-og-app:location:longitude" content="-122.152659"> 
<meta property="your-og-app:location:altitude"  content="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent too many hours on this but it doesn't seem possible. Then I came accross with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565510/how-does-foursquare-add-a-custom-image-annotation-on-their-open-graph-map) answer. I think this feature is currently open only to Foursquare. Facebook API docs doesn't have anything related to this.