# How does foursquare add a custom image annotation on their Open Graph map?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, foursquare

When foursquare works with Open Graph after a user has performed a checkin on their application (and assuming said user is linked to Facebook), foursquare posts to Open Graph a sample of this checkin data. What's interesting is that they do not have a standard map. Their map has a pin point on it in which an annotation embeds a custom image. It looks a little something like this:

[image]

I'm curious how this is done? I can get a regular map to show up with a pin point or a simple image view, but I can't get this custom annotation embedded within a map view.

From what I can tell, there is nothing in the documentation which shows how to further customize the Map layout or add any additional meta data to a GeoPoint object in order to get this additional functionality.

Comment: This might be a custom feature that Facebook awarded them... We've seen it before...

Comment: Is there anyway to confirm this? I'm guessing it would require a response from someone on the Platform team.

Comment: Yep​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I'll ask around and try to find out

Comment: It's currently only in use by Foursquare - effectively it's a test right now, there are plans to open it up more widely but there's nothing to announce right now - it'll be announced on the blog when we open it up further

Comment: Thank you Igy. Maybe you should post this as an answer so I can mark it as the right one and save someone else the trouble?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's currently only in use by Foursquare - effectively it's a test right now.

There are plans to open it up more widely but there's nothing to announce right now - it'll be announced on the blog when opened up further - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/

Comment: those PMD's get all the fun ;)

Comment: Hi lgy. I dont understand this. can i implement like foursquare app?. If so, how can i implement this?. Please share with us.